# C# Regex search string for text including surrounding brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to search a string for '[E1010]' or '[E1011]' or '[E1012]'.  Currently, I can only successfully search without using the brackets [].  How can I adjust my regex to include the texting surrounded by the brackets as it is in my sClientError variable.

Thanks!

```
string sClientErrors = "Bla Blah \"30\" [E1011]\r\nBlah Blah"44\" [E1012]";

    Regex myRegexE10 = new Regex(@"\bE1010\b");
    Regex myRegexE11 = new Regex(@"\bE1011\b");
    Regex myRegexE12 = new Regex(@"\bE1012\b");

    if (myRegexE10.IsMatch(sClientErrors) || myRegexE11.IsMatch(sClientErrors) || myRegexE12.IsMatch(sClientErrors))
    {

           // do code here...

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a "\" if front of a character you want to include, so you would use:

```
Regex myRegexE10 = new Regex(@"\[\bE1010\b\]")
```

You can also use "\\" if you needed to find something like "\s", where "\*" is a Regex option.

Answer (score 2):

By adding the brackets:

```
Regex myRegexE10 = new Regex(@"\[E1010]");
```

or

```
Regex myRegexE1x = new Regex(@"\[E101[012]]");
if (myRegexE1x.IsMatch(sClientErrors)) { ...
```

Note that once you add the brackets, word boundaries are no longer necessary. Note too that you don't need to escape closing square brackets